# Use a batch file to kill LogMeIn Free?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-media-center, logmein, batch-file

When I connect to my media PC using [LogMeIn Free](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/), Windows 7 Media Center shuts down because it doesn't work over a remote desktop connection. This isn't too much of a problem for me as it's the same with Microsoft's Remote Desktop.

In order to get around this limitation with Microsoft's Remote Desktop, I use the following batch file to kill RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol), wait a moment and then re-start Windows Media Center:

```
tscon RDP-Tcp#0 /dest:console
ping -n 5 localhost > NUL
RunDLL32.exe C:\Windows\ehome\ehuihlp.dll,BootMediaCenter
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with LogMeIn Free as the session isn't killed/disconnected. Of course I could just run it and then close the window very fast, but that isn't ideal.

Is there a line I can add into this batch file which will also kill LogMeIn Free if it is connected?

Comment: I love the use of ping > NUL. +1

Comment: Does "kill the logmein exe" meet the requirement of "kill if connected"? Or is it specifically iff you're connected? There's a number of command line apps that can just kill a specified exe if run with sufficient privilages.

Comment: I suppose I could kill the exe, wait 5 seconds and then restart it again - it just seems a little nasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to kill any existing Logmein sessions from command line?

```
logmein.exe restart
```

Looks like it restarts the logmein service. I imagine this would have the desired effect.

([Source](http://logmeinwiki.com/wiki/LogMeIn:Command_Line_Switches_for_logmein.exe))

Comment: Good find. If that doesn't work, you could stop the service, run the ping to wait 5 seconds and then start it again.